# OSLogPrivacy: what's the difference between .private and .sensitive?

Tags: swift, logging

I'm in the process of implementing logging in my app using the new `os.log` API's from iOS 14 / macOS 11.

I've just noticed that we have more choice when it comes to the privacy of the included variables in our logs. There are the classic `public` and `private`, but there's also `auto` and `sensitive`. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogprivacy/3578099-sensitive?changes=__2_8) for the `sensitive` case says that *"this option behaves identically to the private option"*. So why should we use it and what are its benefits?

```swift
Logger.auth.log(level: .debug, "Signed request \(String(describing: request.url), privacy: .sensitive)")
```

(`Logger.auth` is an extension on Logger in my project which just declares a new static logger object. See [this blog post](https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/oslog-unified-logging/) for more informations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only benefit I can guess is to allow multiple "channels" for the developer. You can choose to use [private](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogprivacy/3578097-private?changes=__2_8) for user details and [sensitive](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/oslogprivacy/3578100-sensitive?changes=__2_8) for internal identifiers/ secret details.

This would allow you to choose to **always** redact sensitive values, but only **sometimes** redact private values. However, it's up to you.